# Remove symbol ï»¿ from json response

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am using Volley Library for JSON Parsing, while parsing the response coming is as below :

**JSON RESPONSE :**

```
ï»¿{"category":{"420":{"key":420,"label":{"420":"Acacia"},"count":"1"},"421":{"key":421,"label":.....
```

We can see, at start of the response a symbol is coming   **ï»¿** . How can I remove this symbol from Android side without converting it into string? Because of this symbol I am not able to get JSON Object.

**CODE :**

```
private void jsonRequestGetFilterData() {
    utils.showDialog();
    String url = Constants.FILTER_URL;
    Log.e("URL", "" + url);

    StringRequest eventoReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("RESPONSE", response);
                    utils.hideDialog();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        Log.e("jsonObject",""+jsonObject);

                        JSONObject jsonObjectCategory = jsonObject.getJSONObject("category");
                        Log.e("jsonObjectCategory",""+jsonObjectCategory);



                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        utils.hideDialog();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error: ", "" + error.getMessage());
            utils.hideDialog();

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("customer_id", pref.getString(Constants.SP_CUSTOMER_ID, ""));
            params.put("store_id", pref.getString(Constants.SP_STORE_ID, ""));
            params.put("currency_code", pref.getString(Constants.SP_CURRENCY_CODE, ""));

            Log.e("customer_id",""+pref.getString(Constants.SP_CUSTOMER_ID, ""));
            Log.e("store_id",""+pref.getString(Constants.SP_STORE_ID, ""));
            Log.e("currency_code",""+pref.getString(Constants.SP_CURRENCY_CODE, ""));
            return params;
        }
    };
    eventoReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            60000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));


    AppController.getInstance(FilterActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(eventoReq);
}
```

Comment: @Abhishekkumar - Surely it's already a string.

Comment: Yes, when i am getting response its string only @T.J Crowder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

The characters **ï»¿** is the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) , so you should check your encoding ([UTF-8 with or without BOM](https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html)).

**Solution 2:**

You can convert response string to `UTF-8` like,

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {    
    try {
        response=new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("RESPONSE", response);

    ...................
}
```

Comment: How can i check @Sager , Can you please explain?

Comment: Solution 2 is a very bad idea. If the BOM wasn't handled, the stream was clearly being read with the wrong encoding, and other characters in the stream are likely corrupted.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar, please post your code from where you get this JSON.

Comment: Updated with Code @SagarZala

Comment: I agree with T.J., Solution 2 is terrible and should not be used.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar & Sagar - #2 is still a really bad idea. You're assuming the text has been correctly interpreted as ISO-8859-1, but you don't know that's true. This may work, it may not, but it's certainly not the correct solution.

Answer (score 6):

Your response starts with a byte-order mark ([BOM](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)). At the level where you're reading the response, you need to ensure that the stream or whatever you're using to do that knows the encoding of the response (apparently it's not auto-detecting it). When it knows the correct encoding, it should understand and handle the BOM.

Normally, this is handled via the `Content-Type` header in the response from the server, and that's where it should be fixed. But if for some reason you can't fix it there, usually there's an option when creating the read stream to force an encoding. Yours looks like UTF-8.

**Don't** just use `substring` or similar to skip over it. Other characters in the string may well have been interpreted incorrectly because the wrong encoding is being used. (This isn't just for obscure characters, the £ sign varies by encoding, as does the € and any number of others.)

More: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Can you please explain it by code . I am not getting .

Comment: @Abhishekkumar - You'd have to show us the server code generating the response, since that's where this should be fixed. If for some reason you can't fix it server-side, the **very** much poorer solution is to fix it client-side by (as I said above) forcing an encoding when creating the read stream. You'd have to show us your code reading the string.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar - I see you've added your client-side code. Again: This should be solved **on the server**, by sending the correct `Content-Type` header.

Comment: It means we have to fix it by server_side @T.J.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar - That's the correct place to fix it. It's important to correctly identify the content being sent.

Answer (score 0):

I find a simplest solution for my question. Put below line of code when you are sending `params` for `POST` Request.

**Code Here :**

```
 params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

**Full Code :**

```
----------
 @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

                params.put("username", email.getText().toString().trim());
                params.put("password", pwd.getText().toString().trim());
                return params;
            }
```